# Filepaths within DLL component of ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, unc

I hope this isn't too vague.
I've written a C# component that references my file system with a UNC path.
I'm using it in an ASP.NET web app.
The component works fine within Visual Studio. (as an aside: it also works fine when referenced in a WinForm app).
When I deploy it with the web app to IIS, the compiled DLL in the bin folder, the DLL is failing to locate files with the UNC path.
Any ideas?

Comment: can you show a code snippet on how you reference the UNC path you are referring

Comment: The indentity (User) under which IIS runs probably dosent have persmission to access files out side teh virtual dir. This is one of the common problem with, this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479711/asp-net-reading-and-writing-to-the-file-system-outside-the-application

Comment: What do you mean, fails to locate the file? Is an exception thrown? What exception?

Answer (score 0):

The user running the application pool for that website needs access to that shared folder. Since that's another machine, you're going to have to change the app-pool user from default to one of the following:

1: make a user account with exact same username and password on both machines (where IIS is and the machine hosting the file share)

2: use an active directory account (if you have it available), where it's assumed that both machines are members of the same AD

---

3: Try mapping that UNC folder to a drive letter on the machine where the website is. Maybe (I'm not sure), you'll be able to set [read] permissions for the existing/default app pool user account.

---

The reason it works when you run the app from VS is because it's running under **your** user account (and you're probably admin, having access to that network share also). Same with that desktop app: **you** are running it. ASP.NET apps are ran/executed by a user account that isn't the logged-in user (well, unless you change it to be).

You'll see that you'll need to specify the password for the app-pool account (if you choose to change it). That's because IIS can (will, by default) run even though nobody is **interactively** (human, looking at desktop) logged on to that machine. The app-pool user actually does get logged in to the machine, but not interactively (there's another name for that login mode; "batch" I think). You'll find that user's profile in `c:\users` folder.