# unable to save uploaded file on map network drive in ASP:NET CORE web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a simple ASP.NET Core app in which I have to copy uploaded files in a Server Network Share (a mapped network drive).
This is the code I used:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult loadFile(VM_TRASF TSF)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //create a different file name to save
            string fileNameToUpload = $"example{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")}.pdf";

            //create the file uploaded on destination directory, a server map network drive
            using FileStream FL = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(@"Z:/Mikro-demo/Commesse", fileNameToUpload)) ;
            
            //save the file on the destination directory
            TSF.fileUpload.CopyTo(FL);

            return  Content("ok");
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("errore!");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return Content($"Error: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

So, when I run my web application I get this error:
"Couldn't find the path "

When I run the application in debug mode from my remote ambient the application goes well (I connect to the deploying server by VPN).
To avoid this problem I have read tons of articles, blogs ... but I never find a solution.
I have:

- set the permission READ and WRITE for the IIS_USERS for the mapped drive
- use Network_service mode for the IIS ApplicationPool Identity
- use Impersonation in the WEBCONFIG file

but nothing works!

Comment: instead of mapped unit have you tried to use unc path e.g. \\share.domain.local\share or providing IP address for domain?

Comment: IIS cannot access files above its root (if that is what you're trying to do). To solve it, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711771/debug-with-iis-express-and-access-files-above-root)

Comment: @DanielManta : yes i have done that, but don't work!

Comment: @Ergis : i try to impersonate a user with high level of credentials but i don't know if i have done correctly. There's a lot of examples on the web, but the most are based on old versions of ASP:NET.

Comment: @Michelangelo_Tree you're having trouble impersonating IIS with a built-in account. Assuming you have permission to the remote folder, change authentication to Windows authentication and set the application pool to run using your admin account in IIS.

Comment: @DanielManta i have done this steps but i continue to get Access denied