# editing TXT file on web server using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, text, edit

I am new to programming, specially vb.net.

I am creating a Flash fully-animated website for a customer, that reads its text and images from an outsource (on the same web host).

They requested an admin page to edit the text and images.

I am thinking of making a asp.net page that reads the text file into a dynamic textbox.
The user can edit it then save it, so the Flash player would read the new text.

My question is, do I need to create an FTP connection with the authorization username & password??

Since the asp.net web page would be on the same server, can it open the txt file and edit it and overwrite it without the need for FTP connection??

Answer (score 0):

As far as the ASP.Net engine has access to the folder and file, I think you can go with plain IO to achieve this.

Have a look at [this VB.Net code](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=4492) for reference.

[this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18072/Allow-your-ASP-NET-to-Access-your-Resources) may help in granting access to ASP.Net accounts.

Another method is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479711/asp-net-reading-and-writing-to-the-file-system-outside-the-application)