# Converting bitmap to base64string

Tags: c#, bitmap

I'm trying to add a bitmap to a json string I'm sending to a website.
To do this I'm trying to convert the bitmap into a base64string, but this string turns up to be empty if checked on the website.

This is the code I use to covert the bitmap into a base64string

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"C:\ProgramData\test.jpg", true);
System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
bmp.Save(mStream,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] imageBytes = mStream.ToArray();
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
```

but base64String seems to be empty, yet if I make a bitmap out of it again and save that bitmap to my PC everything seems to be fine.

Comment: What don't you simply do `var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\ProgramData\test.jpg"));` ?

Comment: LB is right. But FYI, I tried your code and it worked fine. I got a non empty base64 string.

Comment: I've noticed that most JSON converters will automatically convert byte[] to a string using base 64 without the programmer having to explicitly do the conversion in code. YMMV.

Comment: @L.B, Why don't you add your comment as an answer so you get credit?

Comment: @Kant because it is not an answer, it shows a simpler way of getting a base64 encoded string of an image but does not explain *"but this string turns up to be empty if checked on the website"*

Answer (score 0):

> To do this I'm trying to convert the bitmap into a base64string, but
>   this string turns up to be empty if checked on the website.

Your code is working when running from console application (btw look at comments you can do it more easily). Problem most likely is that local file system outside your web application is not accessible by web application. Try to read file from your web application folder.

To read file outside of your application folder look at this answer [ASP.NET - Reading and writing to the file-system, outside the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479711/asp-net-reading-and-writing-to-the-file-system-outside-the-application) The easiest way is to impersonate your AppPool with user account with appropriate rights.