# How to create a new file with asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to create a file with asp that prompts the user to give a file name and then it will run Sub CreateFile_Click which will create the new file. The new file should have the same name as the user entered within the prompt.

for some reason im getting

```
+System.IO.File.Create(filepath).Dispose()  
    {"Access to the path 'C:\futu.txt' is denied."} 
     System.UnauthorizedAccessException

<script language="VB" runat="server">
Sub CreateFile_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim strFileName As String = funcParam.Value
    Dim filepath as String = "C:\futu.txt"
If Not System.IO.File.Exists(filepath) Then
   System.IO.File.Create(filepath).Dispose()
End If

 'custom code to create a text file
End Sub
</script>
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
    //ask for user input and then create file
    function CreateFile() {
        //get filename from the user
        var fileName = prompt('Type the name of the file you want to create:', '');
        //if the user clicks on OK and if they have entered something
        if ((fileName) && (fileName != "")) {
            //save the filename to the hidden form field 'funcParam'
            document.forms['myForm'].elements['funcParam'].value = fileName;
            //call the postback function with the right ID
            __doPostBack('CreateFile', '');
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form runat="server" id="myForm">
 <a href="javascript:CreateFile();">Create Text file</a>
 <asp:linkbutton id="CreateFile" runat="server" onclick="CreateFile_Click" />
 <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="funcParam">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you will only have access to `c:` in a windows form app, ASP.NET app all you have access it's the folders inside your current application root folder, for example, `C:\inetpup\mysite`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the permissions for the user running IIS do not allow you to access the file.

[ASP.NET Reading and Writing to the File System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479711/asp-net-reading-and-writing-to-the-file-system-outside-the-application)

This link should help you to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create file in C:\ because in real scenario you don't have access to any location out of your website folder.
if you want to create file, you need to create in inside your web folder. using `Server.MapPath()` will help you with relative path.

the best practice might be having a folder named LocalFile in your webfolder and then use a folder as Drive Letter for instance having folder named "C" or "D" and then create sub folders and files inside them.