# ASP.NET MVC How to display Image from folder outside webroot

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Individual Folder create for each user when they register on website outside the webroot folder.I am able to upload the image and store Image path in database.However,I am unable to display the Image. I am trying to get the path of Image from database using LINQ and display in VIEW but it does not work. I can view only one(from the list of Image)Image when FILESTREAM the image path and retrun using FILESTREAMRESULT

Can anyone please guide me how to achieve it? All I want to do is create folder for each respective user when they register in external folder. Upload Image and display.

Comment: Can you please provide the code you're using to retrieve the information from your database and to display your images?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I would keep files in a secure database or within the application's subfolders. But, here's what I would suggest if you really need to access a different folder on the server.

1. Create a folder on your server's file system ahead of time.
2. On the server, assign permissions to that folder so that the identity used by your application can access it.
3. In your code, write code to access the folder and file path.

Hope that helps!

p.s. here's another Q&A on StackOverflow (with some words of warning) in which the second part of the answer is similar to what I suggested.

- [ASP.NET - Reading and writing to the file-system, outside the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479711/asp-net-reading-and-writing-to-the-file-system-outside-the-application)